# How To Find Open Spaces Given List Of Rectangles

Tags: algorithm, geometry, shapes

I am trying to find the open spaces given list of rectangles. So a base rectangle of a given size has rectangles placed down on it covering space the now open spaces that are not covered by the recently placed rectangles make new rectangles I am trying to find those.

I want to create an algorithm to find those open space rectangles. Any pointer would be greaterly appreciated.

Below are some examples I am trying to reproduce algorithmicaly.

First example:

[image]

Second example:

[image]

Third example :

[image]

Comment: I would think this is a well-studied problem, in part for use in industrial CNC cutting operations. Have you found any related research? Also, could four rectangles form a diamond shape, with each adjacent pair having only a corner in common, with four enclosing a rectangular open space?

Comment: I kind of figured it would be a relativly popular topic but I am not sure where to look for it if there is a nomenclature I do not know or something. Also I would like it if it could be able to share only one corner but It not a requirement.

Comment: Is there a problem with the "naive" approach? Manage a list of "free" rectangles. Initially, this list contains just your "base rectangle". Process all the "placed" rectangles, and remove them from all "free" rectangles they are intersecting with, producing new, smaller, potentially more free rectangles and removing the old "free" rectangles.